# Best approach for database architecture heavily focused on storing data of different fields by year and by months at the same time

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, architecture, jhipster

I need to nail this approach as I think the architecture of the database could age badly if the project becomes big enough.

My problem is that with the current architecture that I have designed, the database would grow exponentially as it lays like this:

```
entity Project {
    projectId Long required
}

entity ProjectData {
    yearId Long required
}

entity ProjectMetaData {
    projectManager String,
    company String,
    agency String
}

entity FinancialData {
    monthId Long required
}

entity KpiInfo {
    otd Long,
    oqd Long,
    cumulatedOqd Long,
    cumulatedOtd Long
}

entity ProductionInfo {
    averageDailyCost Long,
    averageDailyRevenue Long,
    managementWorkload Long,
    internalWorkload Long,
    offshoreWorkload Long
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Project to ProjectMetaData
    ProjectData to FinancialData
}


relationship OneToMany {
    Project to ProjectData
    FinancialData to KpiInfo
    FinancialData to ProductionInfo
}
```

The diagram looks like this:
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9vQe.png)

Basically a **Project** has a unique project ID and each Project has its **ProjectMetaData** and its **ProjectData**, after that for each year that the project has been going on the project has **FinancialData**, and for each month of that year, there is **KpiInfo** and **ProductionInfo**. Therefore if I am getting data from the past 4 years until now it means I am creating around 120+ tables for a single project and this is where I'm concerned, if the app. becomes big enough as I mentioned before this will mean it will not be very scalable afterwards.

Is there any common approach for this kind of data-bases where there are many versions of the same fields?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I haven't made myself very clear, I will be glad to respond to any doubts regarding my question

Comment: It's hard to tell with your column names, but it seems like for the StakeholdersData table, as an example, you can create 7 rows, one for each field.  Check out data normalization, especially the first normal form.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I don't understand your business domain - where do the 120 tables come from ?

Comment: We want to keep track of the KPIs of the projects meaning this we need to store the fields by year version and by month version at the same time. If you look at the diagram for each project the database will generate 28 tables (Project (1), ProjectData(1), ProjectMetaData(1), Financial Data(1), KpiInfo[old ClientData](12 for each month of the year), ProductionInfo[old StakeholdersData](12 for each month of the year)) but that's for a single year of data. I guess I haven't made myself clear with the names I have put in the schema,  I will update them to be more clear

Comment: " If you look at the diagram for each project the database will generate 28 tables (Project (1), ProjectData(1), ProjectMetaData(1), Financial Data(1), KpiInfo[old ClientData](12 for each month of the year),..."  No.  Add the month number as a column in the KpiInfo table and write 12 rows, one row for each month of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once was on a team that had to build a database for an enterprise that had a strange company calendar.  They had a fiscal year, divided into fiscal quarters, divided into fiscal months,  divided into fiscal weeks.  They wanted historical reports grouped by any one of these date groupings.
what we ended up doing was creating a table called Almanac that had one row per day, and the primary key was the date in some suitable format.  The table had columns for Fiscal year, fiscal month, etc.
We then created a generator program that populated this table with about ten years worth of data,  applying all of the company's rules for fiscal date groupings.
When we needed to produce historical summaries based on these groupings,  we simply joined the transaction data to the Almanac table on date,  and then used the Almanac columns for Group By purposes.

You might be able to adapt this concept to your case.  The database will grow,  but the join may be reasonable for some time to come.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell with the limited information you're providing, but I'm going to use one table as an example.

Add the year and month as columns in the table.  Better yet, add a date column.  You could set the day as the 1st or the maximum for that month.

```
entity KpiInfo {
    year
    month
    otd Long,
    oqd Long,
    cumulatedOqd Long,
    cumulatedOtd Long
}
```

This one table will now suffice for all time into the future.  Yes, you will insert 12 rows every year.